# Passing array to watch app with handleWatchKitExtensionRequest

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, watchkit

I have finally managed to get some data to pass to my Apple Watch app from the parent application, however I am now looking to pass an array. At the moment I have it working with a 2 separate strings, however I cannot figure out how to get it to work with 2 arrays.

Here is my current code in the watch app:

```
func reloadTable() {
    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["pfquery_request": "pfquery_request"]) { userInfo, error in
        println("User Info: \(userInfo)")
        println("Error: \(error)")

        var data = (userInfo as NSDictionary)

        if let success = data["success"] as? NSNumber {
            if success.boolValue == true {
                var name = data.objectForKey("Name") as! String
                var waitTime = data.objectForKey("WaitTime") as! String
                println(name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the parent app:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    if let pfqueryRequest: AnyObject = (userInfo as? [String: AnyObject])?["pfquery_request"] {
        var name = ""
        var waitTime = ""

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Park")
        var objects = query.findObjects()

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                name = (object.objectForKey("Name") as? String)!
                waitTime = (object.objectForKey("WaitTime") as? String)!
            }

            reply(["success": true, "name": name, "waitTime": waitTime])
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some example code? I'm looking to pass an array of all of the object names, and waitTimes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though not tested!

```
if let pfqueryRequest: AnyObject = (userInfo as? [String: AnyObject])?["pfquery_request"] {
        var name : [String] = []
        var waitTime : [String] = []

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Park")
        var objects = query.findObjects()

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                name += (object.objectForKey("Name") as? String)!
                waitTime += (object.objectForKey("WaitTime") as? String)!
            }

            reply(["success": true, "name": name, "waitTime": waitTime])
        }
    }
```